# Dynamically Update List/List Items

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

(Small edit: "ce" is a shortcut for "React.createElement")

I have been working on a React/WebSockets/AJAX project for a chat room/message board. I am quite new to React, and I have caught on to most of it but I am having trouble with dynamically updating a list/refreshing its items.

What I want to do is every time my WebSocket receives an "update" message, I want to update the lists with the latest messages. The issue I am having is that they are not displaying anything, even though my update method is being called properly. I am getting no errors.

In my UserPageComponent, I have:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      channelType: "global",
      messageToSend: "",
      target: "",
      globalMessages: [],
      privateMessages: []
    };
}
```

In my UserPageComponent render I have this:

```
... return 'Global Chat: ',
      ce('ul', {id: "globalMessageDiv"}, this.state.globalMessages),
      'Private Chat: ',
      ce('ul', {id: "privateMessageDiv"}, this.state.privateMessages),
...
```

Here is my update (called every time a new message is sent - keep in mind globalMsgs/privateMsgs is populated properly with ALL messages sent as of when it was called).

```
updateData() {
    const globalMsgs = this.getMessages("global");
    const privateMsgs = this.getMessages("private");

    var compiledGms = [];
    var compiledPms = [];

    globalMsgs.map((gm) => {
      var gmToLi = ce('li', gm);
      compiledGms.push(gmToLi);
    });

    privateMsgs.map((pm) => {
      var pmToLi = ce('li', pm);
      compiledPms.push(pmToLi);
    });

    this.setState({globalMessages: compiledGms});
    this.setState({privateMessages: compiledPms});
  }
```

The update function is called whenever I send a message and works like needed. (example below)

I'm unsure what else I can provide, however here is an example of what "globalMsgs" holds: [data in globalMsgs/privateMsgs variables example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ro3A.png)

Comment: If you `console.log` the `compiledGms` and the `compiledPms` variables just before setting the state, are they empty arrays?

Comment: Aha, turns out compiledGms and compiledPms are empty. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: is your ce('li', gm) async?

Comment: See if `globalMsgs` and `privateMsgs` are empty as well. Then you can share the `getMessages` method - maybe there is some asynchronous operation there.

Comment: globalMsgs and privateMsgs are not empty, I have double checked that before posting this as well.

Comment: Then try to log the `gmToLi` and `pmToLi` variables in the console to see what actually is being pushed into  those arrays.

Comment: I figured the issue out with the help of someone else - it was an issue with async in JavaScript, paired with the use of fetch calls for the information used for the List Items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
updateData() {
   const globalMsgs = this.getMessages("global");
   const privateMsgs = this.getMessages("private");

   var compiledGms = [];
   var compiledPms = [];

   for(var i=0;i<globalMsgs.length;i++){
      var gmToLi = ce('li', globalMsgs[i]);
      compiledGms.push(gmToLi);
      if(i==globalMsgs.length-1){
         this.setState({globalMessages: compiledGms});
      }
   }

   for(var i=0;i<privateMsgs.length;i++){
      var pmToLi = ce('li', privateMsgs[i]);
      compiledPms.push(pmToLi);
      if(i==privateMsgs.length-1){
         this.setState({privateMessages: compiledPms});
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and compiledGms and compiledPms are still empty. Here is the output: https://gyazo.com/6cfae74798a2b4a1d03571d6cc5220d7

pms: and gms: are compiledGms and compiledPms. the two arrays above are the result from getMessages for globalMsgs and privateMsgs.